# How to initialize an Array in VBA with the value from an excel cell that contains a square brackets array?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to take an array from a cell that is filled with courses that an user has selected:

```
["Java","Visual Basic for Applications"]
```

I want to copy the elements from the array inside a VBA array:

```
Dim IndividualCourses(1 To 9) As String
```

The array from excel cell can hold min 1 to 10 values an is coming via an Wix form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

```
Sub test()
    Dim data() As Variant
    Dim arrStr As String
    Dim dataItems As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim IndividualCourses(1 To 9) As String

    arrStr = Range("B2")
    arrStr = Replace(Replace(arrStr, "[", "{"), "]", "}")
    data = Application.Evaluate(arrStr)
    dataItems = Application.CountA(data)
    For i = 1 To dataItems
        IndividualCourses(i) = data(i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: How do I iterate as to print this elements from array. I have started learning VBA last night and the struggle is real :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your "array" is in a single Excel cell and is enclosed in "[" and "]", and each item is enclosed in double-quotes, you can do this:

```
Dim CourseList As String
CourseList = "[""Java"",""Visual Basic for Applications""]"
' Strip off "["" and ""]" at each end
CourseList = Mid(CourseList, 3, Len(CourseList) - 4)

' Split at quoted comma delimiter
Dim IndividualCourses() As String
IndividualCourses = Split(CourseList, """,""")
```

It might be better to use a JSON parser.

As this [link](https://myexcelgenius.com/getting-data-from-a-website-in-json-format-using-vba/) says,

> You could write your own VBA code to parse the JSON data.
>
> This approach is only recommended if you have acute masochistic
> tendencies.